# In-app Billing unlock button only one time

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

```
 private Button clickButton;
    private Button buyButton;

    private static final String TAG =
            "InAppBilling";
    IabHelper mHelper;
    static final String ITEM_SKU = "tips";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        buyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buybutton);
        clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        clickButton.setEnabled(false);
        String base64EncodedPublicKey =
                "  "

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.startSetup(new
                                   IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                       public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                           if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                       result);
                                           } else {
                                               Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });

    }


    public void button2 (View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), vtoriFra
                                   gment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void buttonClicked (View view)
    {
        clickButton.setEnabled(false);
        buyButton.setEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), purviFragment.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void buyClick(View view) {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data)
    {
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
                resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                consumeItem();
                buyButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    };
    public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
            } else {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);
            }
        }
    };
    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
            new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
                public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                              IabResult result) {
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        clickButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        // handle error
                    }
                }
            };
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Hi, i have a trouble mit my app. The case is:
I want when the people pay in my app to unlock one button but i want to pay only one thime but when they pay they unlock the button for only one time. Sorry for my bad english. This is my source code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy, but this is your flow:

- when the user clicks the button you start the purchasing flow
- when when purchasing flow ends, you query for the list of purchased items
- if the purchased item exists, you consume it

When you consume an item, you "delete" it, so it is no more on the purchased items list. If you want so sell something just once (for example to remove ads) you don't have to consume it.

Your flow should be this:

- query for the purchased items
- if the list contains the purchase item, disable the button
- if the list doesn't contain che purchase item, enable the button
- on click, start the purchase flow
- when when purchasing flow ends, you query for the list of purchased items
- if the purchased item exists, disable the button and provide the extra feature
- if the purchased item doesn't exists, the purchase procedure failed

You should read carefully this page:
https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html